# Initialize a Java Collection in Class that was declared in Interface

Tags: java, vector, collections, interface

Declared a Vector in the Interface and set it to null, want to initialize it later in the class that implemented the Interface, java is giving error with the following code, how can i initialize it any other way?

```
import java.util.Vector;

interface machine {
    Vector<Integer> temp = null;
    public int compute();
}

class App implements machine {
    App(Vector<Integer> x) {
        //error here, can't assign value to temp as it is declared in interface, any other way of initializing??
        temp = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int compute() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : temp) {
            sum += x;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

public class Finals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Integer> x = new Vector<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x.add(i);
        }
        App a = new App(x);
        System.out.println(a.compute()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `machine.temp` is implicitly `static`, `final`, and `public`. You can't modify a constant. It's in the wrong place. Seems like you need an abstract class between the interface and the class (if that's appropriate for your design)

Comment: You can't declare variables inside interfaces in **Java**. The **contract** that implementing classes must adhere to includes only **methods**. All fields in interfaces are `final`, even if you omit this modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java, the language, is designed with the following ideas in mind:

- Fields are never really considered as part of a type's "public API". Yes, a public field can be written and can be modified from the outside, but almost no java code out there does this, and many language features simply do not support it. For example, method references exists (`someExpr::someMethodName` is legal java), but the there is no such thing as a field reference.
- Interfaces exist **solely** to convey API - to convey what a type is supposed to be able to do, it is *not* a thing that was intended for conveying *how* it is to do it. In other words, interface (hence the name) yes, implementation no.

Add these 2 concepts together and you see why what you want (put a field in an interface) **is not supported**. A field is not part of an interface (rule #1), therefore it must be implementation, and interfaces can not carry implementation details (rule #2), hence: **You cannot put a field in an interface**.

As a consequence, the java lang spec dictates that any field declaration in an interface is inherently `public static final` - it's a constant. You can't make it not-public-static-final - putting `private` on it as modifier is a compiler error. There is no modifier that means 'unstatic'.

You have 2 options:

- You intended that field solely as implementation: You decided that **all** classes that implement this interface will need this field, so, might as well declare it in the interface and save the typing, right? Well, what you're doing there is grouping common aspects of *the implementation* together. Java supports this, but **only in abstract classes**. This happens all the time in java: There is `java.util.List` (an interface), and `java.util.AbstractList` (an abstract class that implements that interface, that provides a bunch of common behaviour), and `java.util.ArrayList` (the most commonly used implementation. It extends AbstractList).
- You actually need the 'interface' part of that field: You want to write some code, either in the interface file itself (via `default` methods), or in code that receives an object whose type is your `machine` interface, and want to directly access the field. When in rome, act like romans. When programming java, act like other java programmers. Which means: Don't treat fields as interface - as API. If the very essence of 'a machine' (that is to say: An object that is an instance of a class, and that class implements `machine`) is that it can provide a list of integers representing the `temp` concept, then **make that part of the interface**: Write `Vector<Integer> getTemp;` in the interface, and let each implementing class provide an implementation. If you expect that all implementing classes likely just want:

```java
private Vector<Integer> temp;

public Vector<Integer> getTemp() {
  return temp;
}
```

Then you can put that in an abstract class which implements the interface, and have all your impls implement the abstract class.

If this is all flying over your head, I can make it simpler:

- All field decls in interfaces are necessarily `public static final`, whether you write it or not. You can't declare fields that aren't, the language simply won't let you.
- There are good reasons for that - see the above explanation.

NB:

You appear to be using some extremely outdated (at least 25 years at this point!!) guidebook. This code wouldn't pass any review as a consequence. `Vector` is obsolete and should not be used, and has been obsolete for 20 years: You want `ArrayList`, presumably. Java conventions dictate that TypesGoLikeThis, methodNamesLikeThis, variableNamesAlsoLikeThis, and CONSTANTS_LIKE_THIS. Thus, it'd be `public interface Machine`, not `public interface machine`. The compiler lets you do whatever you want, but your code is needlessly weird and inconvenient when you integrate it with any other java code if you fail to follow the conventions.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding you can't do it, because interface variables are static final hence you have to initialize in interface itself.